# Why is my Promise always hitting the catch() method?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm using the JavaScript Promise object with a then(), catch().

The console.log in the catch() method always runs, regardless of the response from the API ("STATUS_SUCCESS" or "STATUS_FAILED").

Is this normal behaviour in promises or is there a way to only hit the catch() method if the response has failed?

**Updated with live example:**

```
sendAccountDataToBackend(response) {

    const { formData } = response;

    const requestObj = {
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/validate',
        data: {
            firstname: 'dummy_firstname',
            lastname: 'dummy_lastname',
            email: 'dummyemail'
        }
    };

    let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        account.Utils.globalAjaxRequest(requestObj, (success) => {
            if(success.status === 'STATUS_SUCCESS') {
                resolve();
                console.log('resolved: ', p)
            } else {
                reject();
                console.log('rejected: ', p);
            }
        });
    })

    p.then(() => {
        console.log('Then: ', response);
    }).catch(() => {
        console.log('catch:', response);
    })
}
```

Comment: did you check what the error in the `catch` was?  maybe the ajax call is throwing before your check.

Comment: Are you calling `success.status === 'STATUS_SUCCESS'` inside the ajax api success callback? What is the flow here like?

Comment: Does it print `console.log('resolved: ', p)`?

Comment: No it is not normal - Please provide a working example that reproduces your problem

Comment: my guess is `if(success.status === 'STATUS_SUCCESS')` is never true, because you're not handling asynchronous code properly

Comment: With the comment `// Ajax to API would go here` I'm really suspecting that you're trying to read `success.status` before it is returned and thus entering your `else` block!

Comment: `'STATUS_SUCCESS'` looks like it is supposed to be some sort of constant … but we can't tell what because we don't know where `success.status` comes from: "Ajax to API would go here" is too vague. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: the main problem with your question is, that the code that you are having an issue with is not included in the question ... i.e. it's how you are doing `// Ajax to API would go here` that is wrong

Comment: I think there is an API call for which you are getting this success or any other response. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I've added a example of the use case. Thanks for your responses so far.

Comment: @Madness follow the instructions in my answer and you'll be given a reason why the code in `catch()` runs

Answer (score 2):

You can find the exact cause of the thrown error by printing it.

Change your catch handler to look like this:

```
catch((e) => {
    console.log('Catch', e);
})
```

In addition to "Catch" you will see a description of the error in the console.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was causing the catch to fire thanks to @pfcodes suggestion. I was calling a function within the then() block which was failing. Once removed, it stayed inside then(). Silly mistake that was over looked! Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question:

> Is this normal behaviour in promises or is there a way to only hit the catch() method if the response has failed?

It is easy to demonstrate that the `catch` is only entered when the `reject` call is made.

```js
function testPromise(shouldReject)
{
  return  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       setTimeout(function(){
           if(shouldReject) reject();
           else resolve();
       },1000);
  });
}

function handlePromise(p, name){

  p.then(() => {
      console.log(name, 'Then');
  }).catch(() => {
      console.log(name, 'Catch');
  })
}

var rejectPromise = testPromise(true);
var resolvePromise = testPromise(false);
handlePromise(rejectPromise,"reject");
handlePromise(resolvePromise,"resolve");
```

So, what this means is that in your code, for whatever reason (probably badly handled asynchronous ajax call) you're entering the `else` block.

---

Regarding your update, I would say that `success.status` is returning something *other* than "STATUS_SUCCESS" for the reasons demonstrated by the code above.

Try adding `console.log(success)` inside the ajax callback.

```
account.Utils.globalAjaxRequest(requestObj, (success) => {
    console.log(success);
    ....
```